# oracle forms 6i missing package body

Tags: sql, oracle, oracleforms

In a software we've acquired, we found that there are some package bodies that have procedures that are just defined as null. For example:

```
procedure execute_report(parameters) is
begin
    null;
end;
```

Despite this, these procedures are being used through the forms, and they seem to work properly. As in the example, calling the procedure "execute_report" actually runs a report.
The procedure is not defined in any library, or even using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME LIKE '%EXEC%'
```

does not return anything from the database that might be called...

Is there a way to hide the code in the forms, libraries or DB that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you checking the same database that the forms are using? Which user are you running the `ALL_OBJECTS` query from? Is it a SYSDBA account or an ordinary user? Are the forms connecting to the same user?

Comment: @MT0 I'm running the query with the same user as the forms are using. No, it's not SYSDBA. I guessed that if the form is able to see it I should be able as well with the same user. I do not have access through SYSDBA, I should have to contact the DBA for that.

Comment: The existence of a procedure called "execute_report" *within a package* is irrelevant - if your code calls `execute_report` directly (i.e. without specifying the package name), and it succeeds, then you should expect to find (a) a *procedure* created on the database by that name, or (b) a synonym for it.

Comment: Did you check whether procedure named EXECUTE_REPORT exists among form's own procedures? You'd check that in one of nodes of the Object Navigator.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I was unable to find the procedure in the database as mentioned in the question... Do you know any other way to look for it?

Comment: @Littlefoot I can confirm the procedure is NOT in the form´s own procedures. It only exists in one of the incorporated libraries, but the package body only has the null definition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a pll (forms library) that contains the procedure execute_report
Then this will be called instead of the database version.

Comment: Yeah, but as mentioned, it just says null; in the definition of the procedure.